# Google doesn't have in-built application page like Keycloak how we can create our own custom dashboard page to mimik the keycloak application page

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, google-workspace

We need to have all our internal app like Jenkins, Redmine etc link and access, inside google like in Keycloak application page thus google support the this feature.